bulk convert lon lat coordinates to EPSG 3031 (antarctic) coordinates using python
I am trying to write a code that will bulk convert lon lat coordinates to EPSG 3031 so that I can plot them in the Polar ToolKit through Python.  I have lon lat coordinates on an excel sheet.  How can I do this?

It depends on your toolkits. I would use geopandas (https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html), and convert projection, or maybe just pyproj. It is pretty standard job to do in python, but it depends on how you work data in python and output
